# Best IDE for fast prototyping with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ide, spyder, halcon

I want to ask about the best IDE to prototype programs by using OpenCV library.

I’ve been programming with Halcon for 3 years and I would like to learn how to program with OpenCV too. I was thinking about reproducing some old programs that I have created with Halcon, but instead using OpenCV. The problem is that maybe I’m not using the correct IDE (I’m programming with Python using Spyder) or maybe programming with OpenCV is slower than I have expected (I don't discard the possibility that I don’t know the appropriate way to prototype properly by using these tools).

I already know I come from an expensive program that allows me to work with many comforts, but I miss having a window where I can display dynamically the results of the operations than I’m applying. Also, draw some ROIs quickly. Anyways, do you think I’m using the right tools? Do you know some tutorials from which I can learn how to prototype quickly using that IDE?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for OpenCV prototyping in a GUI is a program called **GRIP (Graphically Represented Image Pipeline)**. You can download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/WPIRoboticsProjects/GRIP/releases/tag/v1.5.2).
It supports many inputs: single image, multiple images, webcam, and even HTTP cameras. You get all the key OpenCV commands, along with some custom ones developed by WPI. 
[image: GRIP_Pipeline]

You develop your image processing flow as a pipeline, with filtering blocks such as desaturate, find contours, etc. in which you string the output from one block to the input of another (or multiple). You can then export the pipeline to Python, Java, or C++ (exported as a usable class with a key `process` function). **If you want to see an example, feel free to check out this previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272269/python-opencv-optimal-thresholding/64273709#64273709) I wrote!**